# How can I mark the values from one table, that are not in another table (mySQL)?

Tags: php, html, mysql

In mySQL this is my table `animals`:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| animal_ID |  name  | animal |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|         1 | alan   | dog    |
|         2 | sam    | frog   |
|         3 | marion | cat    |
|         4 | george | rabbit |
|         5 | bob    | bird   |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

and this is my table `orders`

```
+----------+-----------+
|   date   | animal_ID |
+----------+-----------+
| 02.03.16 |         4 |
| 12.04.16 |         3 |
| 18.07.16 |         1 |
+----------+-----------+
```

I want to list all animals but mark the animals that are NOT in the orders table red. This is my expected result

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <td>alan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:red">sam</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>marion</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>george</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="color:red">bob</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have now the problem, that I do not know how to list all animals from the animal table, I just get the animals in my list that are not in the orders table:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE  o.animal_ID = a.animal_ID)';
```

Here my result is this:

```html
 <table >
      <tr>
        <td>alan</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>marion</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>george</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Simply query from the `animals` table and print and also check in the `order` table, If it is in the table or gives you some output then add the style of red.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if every primary key value is being referenced as foreign key in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761363/how-to-check-if-every-primary-key-value-is-being-referenced-as-foreign-key-in-an)

Comment: @AT-2016 Yes, the names of the animals

Comment: get the data using left join, keep the animals table on left, the column where you see null are basically the ones that are not in the order table...

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, This is may be the solution, Also my answer doing fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this script using two query.

```
 1. Query for all the animals.
 2. Query with the animals ID in the orders.
```

The first one is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals";
```

Loop this and check in the `order` table inside the first loop-

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE  animal_ID = fetched_animal_ID";
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql2) > 0){
    // print the normalrows here
}else{
    // print the red rows here
}
```

==============================================================

You can do this using the LEFT JOIN as well-

```
$sql = "SELECT *, o.animal_ID as o_animal FROM animals a LEFT JOIN orders o 
        ON a.animal_ID = o.animal_ID";
```

[Online Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42597/1)

Now you need to check the `o_animal` if it is null or empty then use the `red` rows and else the normal.

If you have any question please ask me.

Comment: This one is good, but against every record there will be a database call.

Comment: I also think about the LEFT JOIN, But I thought the straight forward will be preferable, and I help **Jarla** a number of time, so i can understand her.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use your second solution. To test it I wrote it like you suggested and then `foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {  echo '<td>'.$row['name'].' </td>'; }` But now my table is empty. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Or do you mean to use the second solution also inside the loop?

Comment: Oh no I did a mistake, now it is not empty, but I have more then 5 entries now in my table

Comment: Can you please do it using the first solution? The LEFT JOIN always join right tables data into left table and sometime it will be more than the first one, Because of the miss match of Data in two tables.

Comment: The first solution is fine, but with this solution for every loop I have another database call. I would love to avoid this, do you think it is possible?

Comment: YES, You can use the second solution. If you can make a fiddle on sqlfiddle with your two table then i can handle this.

Comment: I will give it a try!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124520/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-jarla).

Answer (score 1):

You can try another method without using join query.

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$sq=mysqli_query($conn,'select * from orders');
$i=0;
$ar=array();
while($re=mysqli_fetch_array($sq))
{
$anid=$re['animal_ID'];
$ar[$i]=$anid;
$i++;
}
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from animals");
?>
<table >
    <?php

while($all=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if(in_array($all['animal_ID'],$ar))
    {
       ?>

    <tr>

        <td><?php echo $all['name'];?></td>
    </tr
    <?php
    }

else
{
  ?>  <tr>

        <td style="color:red"><?php echo $all['name'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple negation?

```
$sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE  o.animal_ID = a.animal_ID)';
```

Or maybe grab the count with a sub query, highlight the zeroes...

```
$sql = 'SELECT  a.*,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE animal_ID = a.animal_ID)
        FROM animals a';
```